# How to set a signer as optional using embedded sign api

Tags: docusignapi

In embedded signing procedure, I have 2 signers, I need to generate signhere tabs for two signers, but one of signers is optional. The optional signer can sign or leave it blank. How to set optional signer using embedded api.

Answer (score 0):

There are the (https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-add-recipients) Manager Recipient types that you can use for this purpose. Basically you add an additionally recipient role and assign that user as the "Specify recipients" role. Then when the envelope is sent to them they can decided if they themself should be the signing recipient or someone else. The two roles would need to be at a separate signing order because you can't have the same person fill two spots at the same order lever.
So, you can't do an optional recipient per-se, you can add a special type of recipient that can then specify additional recipients.